# D3.js - secondary axis alignment

Tags: d3.js, alignment

I have been looking around for quite a long time now, it seems that I am not the only one to ask but no working answers yet:

Generally, how can we align a secondary axis in D3 (Y2 ticks in front of Y1 ticks)?

I am not especially looking for a bit of code; even a general idea or algorithm could help me. The idea is to have something like this guy did in Highchart:

jsfiddle.net/jugal/3qdkc/

Any clues?

Comment: Get the projected values for the first axis (e.g. by running `scale.ticks()` through the scale) and pass those to `scale2.invert()` to get the corresponding values for the second domain. Pass those values to `.tickValues()` for the second axis.

Comment: Thanks a lot, so easy in the end! It helped me understand better D3 scales by the way.
Please post as an answer so that I can validate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a scale's [`.invert()` function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#linear_invert) to convert projected (screen) coordinates back to values in the original domain. Bearing this in mind, the process is

- Get the projected values for the first axis. If you want those to be the tick values, use `scale.ticks()` and pass them to the first scale to convert to screen coordinates.
- Now pass those values to `scale.invert()` for the second axis scale. This will give you the values in the domain of the second scale.
- Pass those values to `.tickValues()` of the second axis.